# Error when serving static react website with express.js and a route path

Tags: reactjs, express, vite

I'm trying to build a website with express and the vite react template, both using typescript.

If I serve my static files with
`server.use('/', express.static('../mySite/dist'));`
I can access the page with no problems, but if I try to add a prefix like in
`server.use('/site', express.static('../mySite/dist'));`
I get a blank page and an error in the browser's console that says "Loading module from “http://localhost:6969/site/” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”)."

I also tried adding
`<base href="/site" />`
and variations of this in the head tag of my index.html but it didn't change anything. Any idea?